# Coundn't upgrade ruby to install shopify client

Tags: ruby, shopify, ubuntu-18.04

I'm getting this error while installing the Shopify client.

```
[sudo] password for massil: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'shopify-cli' instead of './shopify-cli-2.1.0.deb'
The following NEW packages will be installed
  shopify-cli
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove, and 1 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/956 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /<path-to-.deb-file>/shopify-cli-2.1.0.deb shopify-cli all 2.1.0 [956 B]
(Reading database ... 337058 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../shopify/shopify-cli-2.1.0.deb ...
ERROR:  Error installing shopify-cli:
    There are no versions of theme-check (~> 1.1) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems. Maybe try installing an older version of the gem you're looking for?
    theme-check requires Ruby version >= 2.6. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.
dpkg: error processing archive /<path-to-.deb-file>/shopify-cli-2.1.0.deb (--unpack):
 new shopify-cli package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /<path-to-.deb-file>/shopify-cli-2.1.0.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems to be a problem in ruby version 2.5. I tried updating it to a higher version with `apt`, but it kept telling me that it was up to date. I then used `rbenv` and `rvm` to install higher versions, but it seems to be using, always, the system installed one, to install the Shopify client.

I'm using `ubuntu 18.04`

**EDIT:**
I ended up using `gem install shopify-cli _2.7.2_ --version` for the installations.

Comment: If you want to upgrade your ruby with rvm there are two things you need to do post installation. 1) Source rvm correctly in ~/.bashrc (you know you've done right when `which rvm` returns a lot of lines; it's an alias) and 2) run `rvm use <version> --default`. That will keep system from using its own ruby. Also Bundler is great when you get into the higher rubies.

Comment: Thank! That helped for the installation, of the client, with `apt`

Comment: what you mean with gem install shopify-cli _2.7.2_ --version, putting the ruby version doesn't work for me, got "ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '_2.7.2_' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '2.6' (>= 0) in any repository
"

Comment: I found out the meaning above, but basically is not working because the ruby version is anyway lower then the 2.6 required https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ruby-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: I just opened a ticket as I am not familiar with shopify stack and especially Ruby https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/issues/1617

Comment: I was able to install ruby >3.0 following steps detailed here https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that

theme-check library is not working with ruby lower then 2.6.

Unfortunately installing ruby with the standard way of :

```
sudo apt install ruby-full
```

does install the version:

ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

but an higher version can be installed following the `rbenv` method

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby- 
build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> 
~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

rbenv install 3.0.2
rbenv global 3.0.2
ruby -v
```

after the version of ruby should be

ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-linux]

and running

```
 gem install shopify-cli
```

does install the latest shopify-cli

if this method does not work, try with the other 2 described here [Install Ruby On Rails on
Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/18.04)